# Clear data after ajax request succes

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm sending data from form' to database with ajax post request. After request succes, pushing data to an array in storage. In order not to load all from Backend API again. It works fine.

But, after pushing data to an array I need to clear form, to let user add another data. And it clears form before pushing it to array.

### AddToDB.vue

```
<template>
<div class="addToDB">
    <form @submit.prevent="add">
        <label> Name </label>
        <input type="text" v-model="form.name"/> <br/>
        <label> Price </label>
        <input type="number" v-model="form.price"/> <br/>

        <button>Add</button>
    </form>
</div></template>
```

---

```
<script>
    import axios from 'axios'

    export default {
    name: "AddToDB",
    data() {
        return {
            form: {
                name: '',
                price: ''
            }
        };
    },
    methods: {
        add(){
            axios.post("http://test.com/add', this.$data.form, {
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": `TOKEN`
                }
            })
            .then((response) => {
                this.$store.commit('addList', this.form);

                return Promise.resolve();
            })
            .then(() => this.clearForm());
        },
        clearForm(){
            this.form.name = '';
            this.form.price = '';
        }

      }
  }
</script>
```

---

and store.js

```
export default {
state: {
    list: []
},
getters: {
    getList(state){
        return state.list;
    }
},
mutations: {
    addList(state, $data){
        state.list.push($data);
    }
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```js
// Your current code (not working)...
/*
  axios.post('http://test.com', this.$data.form, {
      headers: {
          "Authorization": `Bearer ${this.$store.getters.currentUser.token}`
      }
  })
  .then((response) => {
      this.$store.commit('addList', this.form);
  })
  .finally(() => this.clearForm())
*/

// Updated code...
axios.post('http://test.com', this.$data.form, { headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.$store.getters.currentUser.token}` } })
  .then((response) => {
    this.$store.commit('addList', this.form);
    
    return Promise.resolve();
  })
  .then(() => this.clearForm());
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not work. Doing the same, pushing empty form.

Comment: Then you are going to need to post more details about your codebase because, based on what you have provided, it should work. Can you provide more code samples?

Comment: Added some code. And why its so hard to past a code here?!